# Recommended way to handle sprite assets for different screen densities (Android)

Tags: android, assets, sprite

I am currently working on a 2D game for Android. All of the images that I render were created as SVG's and then exported to PNG's which I have placed in my assets directory. These images are also all sprites that I render using a sprite batcher.

My question is around using different versions of the sprites for devices with different densities. I know that when developing a traditional android app you could place separate directories for separate density levels inside of res and then place the correctly sized versions of the images in question in these sub-directories of res.

What is a good approach when dealing with sprite images in the asset directory? Should I just have one copy of the sprites at a really high density / resolution that I use for everything and I just render them on a coordinate system that is independent of screen size or should I resize the image based on screen density before I process it to create all my texture regions? Or is there another solution entirely?

Currently I have one high resolution set of sprites that I use for everything, it just seems wasteful and inefficient for the lower density devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best answer(s) that I got to this question are on gamedev.stackexchange: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69970/recommended-way-to-handle-sprite-assets-for-different-screen-densities-android